# Can I restore deleted git repo

Tags: git

I have deleted git repo from my machine accidentally. Now on running any git command I get: "fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git"

I had some locally committed some code changes, which were pending being pushed to the Git repo.
If I checkout the master again, is there a way that I can get my locally committed code OR have I lost that ?

Comment: If you literally deleted the .git directory or the parent directory containing the .git directory then you are lost.

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the repo from the remote, and you will get what is in the remote at this time.
Your local changes were not pushed to the remote, so they are lost.

(There are some disk recovery utilities that can sometimes find data from erased files, because the file don't actually get erased; the file data structure just removes the pointer to the file and puts the space back in the open pool. This is not git related, just a possible recovery option. )